# How messangers handle so many clients?

Tags: python, sockets

I was thinking of a messenger to code.

And the only way that came to my mind was that creating a thread per client (which is a socket). But it is not efficient and I don't think it is possible to create thousands of threads.

So my question is that: How a messenger server handle this many clients?? and how to program that (specially in python)??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is way too broad for the scope of answers here. Basically, don't be surprised if programs actually DO create thousands of threads (on strong enough servers).

Comment: So you mean servers of messengers like Telegram handle millions of users by millions of threads? @OferSadan

Comment: @JacksonJones multiple threads, on multiple processes, on multiple servers - probably, yes